# Entity Framework query executes multiple times for one request on load test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, load-testing

Little bit of background before I go on to explain the problem.

I have a logging mechanism in place which logs

1. Begin and End Http Requests
2. Queries that Entity Framework executes

So I create a simple "AllowAnonymous" MVC Action Method which runs one simple Entity Framework Query. I push that to our DEV server and go to the browser and make call to that Action Method. Check the logs, I see 1 Http Request and 1 Query Executed. Perfect!

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetInvoiceById(int InvoiceId)
    {
        JsonResult mJson = new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        try
        {
            var inv = GetInvoice(InvoiceId);

            mJson.Data = inv;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return mJson;
    }
    public InvoiceViewModel GetInvoice(int InvoiceId)
    {   
        var inv = Context.Invoices.Where(m => m.InvoiceId == InvoiceId)
            .Select(s => new InvoiceViewModel()
            {
                InvoiceId = s.InvoiceId,
                StatusId = s.StatusId,
                AttachmentTypeId = s.TypeId,
                ContentId = s.ContentId,
                CreatedDate = s.CreatedDate,
                UpdatedDate = s.UpdatedDate
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        return inv ?? new InvoiceViewModel();
    }
```

Now I wanted to load test this action method. I used [Netling](https://github.com/hallatore/Netling) for that.

So I ran a load test on 1 thread for 60 seconds. So it makes sequential calls to the action method for 60 seconds. And here are the results for the test.

Netling reported (which I confirmed from my logs) that it ran **345** requests.
But the number of times Entity Framework ran the query is **399** times. So somehow Entity Framework is running the query more than one time for few requests. I am making only one call at a time and there is nobody on DEV server except me.

Additional notes, I see sometimes that number of connections EF has opened and closed are equal to the number of requests and sometimes they are equal to the number of times the query is executed. But whenever I load test the number of query executions are more than the number of requests. If I increase the number of threads the gap between number of requests and number of query executions increase too.

My question is, if it's not already obvious, The number of requests(**345**) should have matched the number of times the query executed(**399**). But it didn't, this means that for some requests the query is executed multiple times. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your question? And where is your code?

Comment: @AFriend The number of requests(345) should have matched the number of times the query executed(399). But it didn't, this means that for some requests the query is executed multiple times. Why?